# Do I still get a free satellite if I skip the tutorial?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

My first game was Classic Ironman, and things went pretty well for a while. I got a free satellite at some point during the tutorial and even managed to survive for a few missions afterwards! Then all my veterans got wiped out on a bomb disposal mission, and my next two teams of redshirts got wiped out in the next two missions. It was pretty much game over.

Since then, I've started probably 15 new games of Classic Ironman, skipping the tutorial, and in a few of them I've made it a few missions past the first UFO crash before giving up and restarting after calamity fell. However, I never seem to get a free satellite in these non-tutorial games.

I don't specifically remember what triggered the free satellite in the tutorial, so maybe I just haven't gotten far enough. Or, in some games, I'd already been building one, so maybe it wouldn't give me a free one since I didn't have extra satellite uplinks. Or maybe if you skip the tutorial, you just don't get one at all!

I'd like to know if you get a free satellite if you skip the tutorial, and if so, what conditions have to occur for that to happen.

Comment: The free satellite is from a council mission early on. I can't remember exactly what they wanted you to do.

Comment: Playing on easy + tutorial skip, and I started with 2 sats - one was already flying over my base, and another in reserve ready to launch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You get a free satellite either by going through the tutorial or by just playing on Normal.
You don't get one on Classic and I imagine you don't get one on Impossible either.

Comment: On Impossible, all you get is a kick in the nuts.

Answer (score 3):

When I played through the tutorial on Classic, I started with one satellite, and was prompted to launch another (that I did not have to pay for) as part of the tutorial mission.

When I later played while **skipping** the tutorial on Normal, the Situation Room still showed me with a "free" satellite.

So as far as you can tell, you don't get a "Free" satellite by going through the tutorial. (At least, on the first 2 difficulties)

Comment: Maybe you only get it on Classic with the tutorial, then. I haven't  had a free one in my situation room on any of my Classic games.

Comment: weird, I started a classic game last night and did not have a free satellite.  I had to build one.  Or maybe its because I haven't intentionally advanced the 'story' yet by capturing an alien.